# preProc = c("center", "scale") meaning in caret's package (R) and min-max normalization

Tags: r, neural-network, normalization, r-caret

I am wondering how `preProc` can be used within the `train()` function of `caret`. I am running a neural network in the `train()` function using `neuralnet`. The code comes from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62199352/setting-hidden-layers-and-neurons-in-neuralnet-and-caret-r/).

This is actually the code:

```
nn <- train(medv ~ ., 
            data = df, 
            method = "neuralnet", 
            tuneGrid = grid,
            metric = "RMSE",
            preProc = c("center", "scale", "nzv"), #good idea to do this with neural nets - your error is due to non scaled data
            trControl = trainControl(
              method = "cv",
              number = 5,
              verboseIter = TRUE)
            )
```

The original data is not scaled, so that it is recommended to scale the data before running the neural network.

However, in the argument `preProc` appears three elements: `center`, `scale`, `nzv`. I am having problems interpreting those values, as I do not know why they are present. Furthermore, I would like to scale/normalize my data using min-max. This would be the function:

```
maxs = apply(pk_dc_only$C, 2, max)
mins = apply(pk_dc_only$C, 2, min)
scaled = as.data.frame(scale(df, center = mins, scale = maxs - mins))
```

Is it possible to normalize my data using min-max scaling within `preProc`?

And if so, how could I undo the scaling when predicting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three options c("center", "scale", "nzv") does scale and center, in the [vignette](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-86/topics/preProcess):

> method = "center" subtracts the mean of the predictor's data (again
>   from the data in x) from the predictor values while method = "scale"
>   divides by the standard deviation.

And `nzv` basically excludes variables that have near zero variance, meaning they are almost constant and most likely not useful for prediction. To do min max, there is an option:

> The "range" transformation scales the data to be within ‘rangeBounds’.
>   If new samples have values larger or smaller than those in the
>   training set, values will be outside of this range.

we try it below:

```
library(mlbench)
data(BostonHousing)
library(caret)

idx = sample(nrow(BostonHousing),400)
df = BostonHousing[idx,]
df$chas = as.numeric(df$chas)
pre_mdl = preProcess(df,method="range")

nn <- train(medv ~ ., data = predict(pre_mdl,df),
method = "neuralnet",tuneGrid=G,
metric = "RMSE",trControl = trainControl(
method = "cv",number = 5,verboseIter = TRUE))

nn$preProcess
Created from 400 samples and 13 variables

Pre-processing:
  - ignored (0)
  - re-scaling to [0, 1] (13)

summary(nn$finalModel$data)


          crim                zn             indus             chas       
 Min.   :0.000000   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.0000  
 1st Qu.:0.000821   1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.:0.1646   1st Qu.:0.0000  
 Median :0.002454   Median :0.0000   Median :0.2969   Median :0.0000  
 Mean   :0.042130   Mean   :0.1309   Mean   :0.3804   Mean   :0.0625  
 3rd Qu.:0.039150   3rd Qu.:0.2000   3rd Qu.:0.6466   3rd Qu.:0.0000  
 Max.   :1.000000   Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :1.0000  
      nox               rm              age              dis         
 Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.00000  
 1st Qu.:0.1276   1st Qu.:0.4470   1st Qu.:0.4032   1st Qu.:0.08522  
 Median :0.2819   Median :0.5076   Median :0.7503   Median :0.20133  
 Mean   :0.3363   Mean   :0.5232   Mean   :0.6647   Mean   :0.25146  
 3rd Qu.:0.4918   3rd Qu.:0.5880   3rd Qu.:0.9361   3rd Qu.:0.38622  
 Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :1.00000  
      rad              tax            ptratio             b         
 Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.0000  
 1st Qu.:0.1304   1st Qu.:0.1770   1st Qu.:0.5106   1st Qu.:0.9475  
 Median :0.1739   Median :0.2729   Median :0.6862   Median :0.9861  
 Mean   :0.3676   Mean   :0.4171   Mean   :0.6243   Mean   :0.8987  
 3rd Qu.:1.0000   3rd Qu.:0.9141   3rd Qu.:0.8085   3rd Qu.:0.9983  
 Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :1.0000  
     lstat           .outcome     
 Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.0000  
 1st Qu.:0.1492   1st Qu.:0.2683  
 Median :0.2705   Median :0.3644  
 Mean   :0.3069   Mean   :0.3902  
 3rd Qu.:0.4220   3rd Qu.:0.4450  
 Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :1.0000
```

Not very sure what you mean by "undo the scaling when predicting". Maybe you meant translating them back to the original scale:

```
test = BostonHousing[-idx,]
test$chas = as.numeric(test$chas)
test_medv = test$medv
test = predict(pre_mdl,test)
```

The range is stored under the preProcess model, under

```
pre_mdl$ranges
         crim  zn indus chas   nox    rm   age     dis rad tax ptratio      b
[1,]  0.00632   0  0.46    1 0.385 3.561   2.9  1.1691   1 187    12.6   0.32
[2,] 88.97620 100 27.74    2 0.871 8.780 100.0 12.1265  24 711    22.0 396.90
     lstat medv
[1,]  1.73    5
[2,] 36.98   50
```

So we write a wrapper:

```
convert_response = function(value,mdl,method,column){
bounds = mdl[[method]][,column]
value*diff(bounds) + min(bounds)
}

plot(test_medv,convert_response(predict(nn,test),pre_mdl,"ranges","medv"),
ylab="predicted")
```

[image]